# How do I handle form data from a form with multiple fields in node?

Tags: node.js, forms, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to build a page for people to RSVP for a wedding website. The guest types in their email address, and the page finds all guests that appear on that invitation and then generates a table:

```
<%- include("./partials/header") %>
<h2>
    RSVP
</h2>




<div class="container">
    <div class=" row justify-content-center">
        <h5>Enter the email address that appears on your invitation.</h5>
    </div>
    <div class=" row justify-content-center">
        <div id="form-findGuest">
            <form action="/rsvp" method="GET">
                <input type="text" name="searchEmail" placeholder="email">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <form action="/rsvp" method="POST">
            <table class="table">
                <% for(i=0;i<guests.length;i++){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%= guests[i].name %></td>  
                        <% if(guests[i].isComing){ %>
                            <td>Attending</td>
                        <% } else { %>
                            <td>Not Attending</td>
                        <% } %>
                        <td>
                        <td>
                                <input type="checkbox">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <% }%>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <a href="/index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>



<%- include("./partials/footer") %>
```

The problem is that I don't know what to do with the post route. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
app.post("/rsvp", (req, res)=>{
//  parse the req.body and for each rsvp that got sent here, add it to some array
//  now use a for loop to iterate through that array and change the isComing value for each guest
    res.redirect("index")
})
```

But I can't figure out how to parse the req.body when I don't know how many fields are going to be in the request- some email addresses may correspond to only one guest, but others may correspond to, say, five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Body parser if not added already, and make use of

> Object.keys

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    
app.post("/rsvp", (req, res)=>{
var keys = Object.keys(req.body);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++)
{
var guest=req.body[keys[i]];
//  now use this to change the isComing value for each guest
}

    res.redirect("index")
})
```

Comment: welcome @DidymusHirsch plz give 'accept answer',so that this question will be closed